# Wp не выводит все виджеты в сайдбаре

Tags: wordpress, вывод, виджет

Здравствуйте , возникла проблема с выводом виджетов, регистрировал в шаблоне вот таким вот образом, на самом сайте выводит всего 8 виджетов , а их зарегистрировано и заполнено в админке 12.. 6 слева и 6 справа, в чем может быть проблема? подскажите пожалуйста

```
  if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

   $args = array(
        'name' => '%d-лево',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
    );
 register_sidebars( 6, $args );
}

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

   $args = array(
        'name' => '%d-право',
        'before_widget' => '</div><div id="sidebar-right"><div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
    );
     register_sidebars( 6, $args );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как вы потом выводите сайдбары? Я не вижу в параметрах их id. По идее вы должны задать в массиве что-то вроде `'id' => 'test-sidebar'`, а потом вывести сайдбар там, где вам нужно, функцией `dynamic_sidebar('test-sidebar');`.

Например, функция регистрации сайдбара:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(
        array(
            'name' => '1-лево',
            'id' => 'test-sidebar',
            'before_widget' => '',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title' => '</h2>',
            'after_widget' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Затем, где-то на странице выводим этот сайдбар со всеми виджетами, которые вы в него поместили: `dynamic_sidebar('test-sidebar');`

Comment: то есть потом нужно все 12 сайдбаров так выводить каждый отдельно ?

Comment: Первые 8 по списку я отдельно заполнял в админке, в разделе виджеты, как только я в них что нибудь добавлял они отображались на сайте , вывод шел функцией `<?php get_sidebar(); ?> `

Comment: вот вместо функции `get_sidebar();` вам нужна функция `dynamic_sidebar()`, которой нужно передавать `id` вашего сайдбара

Comment: Правильно ли я понял ? что б потом вывести 12 сайдбаров мне нужно будет 12 раз вызвать функцию `dynamic_sidebar()` ?

Comment: Ну если у вас 12 сайдбаров (не путайте с виджетами внутри сайдбаров), то да :) можно выводить в цикле, если они будут следовать подряд

Comment: я понял )) сейчас попробую ))

Comment: ой, если выводить каждую отдельно то с дизайном беда , не получается, все уезжает , стили не применяются..  может можно как нибудь вывести всё сразу ?

Comment: меня интересует почему не выводятся все 12 через `get_sidebar()` , когда через functions.php задаю каждый сайдбар отдельно ... таким образом `if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {

    register_sidebar(array(
         'id' => '1',
  'name' => '1',
  'before_widget' => '<div class="sb-bot"><div class="sb-top"> <div class="sb-right"><div class="sb-left"><div class="sb-rb"><div class="sb-lb"><div class="sb-rt"><div class="sb-lt">',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>'
 ));

}`

Comment: `get_sidebar()` выводит код, который у вас расположен в `sidebar.php`, а не зарегистрированные сайдбары

Comment: Все )) разобрался)) спасибо вам большое) в файле `sidebar.php` было всего 8 функций) .. `<?php
 if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar(8) ) : endif;
?>`

Comment: из за глупости провозился целый день ))

Comment: бывает :) главное, что разобрались :)